# Mysqli statement returning warnings

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($var) . "')");
if ($sql) {echo "connection successful";
} else {
echo "failure";
}
```

It returns these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
```

I tried using PDO but that didn't work either...

Comment: simply pass connection link identifier in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Parameter is mysql connection link identifier, and second is string For more details, you can visit this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

```
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = mysqli_query(pass_your_connection_identifier_here ,"INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string(pass_your_connection_identifier_here, $var) . "')");
if ($sql) {echo "connection successful";
} else {
echo "failure";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing connection identifier in both `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query()`
change your code to `mysqli_query($connection,$sql)` and `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$string)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing connection variable at both the lines that's why you are facing issues :

Try to replace your code with this :

```
//$con // it is your connection variable
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$var) . "')");
if ($sql) {echo "connection successful";
} else {
echo "failure";
}
```